# Predicate logic by resolution

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I've been trying to study logic lately, as part of my AI course, and I've been going through some old, simple exam questions from my school. There is one question about resolution in particular that I don't know how to solve (there are no answers/explanations provided). So, here goes:

Sonny, Bonny and Conny are all elephants. We know that:

1. Sonny is gray.
2. Conny is pink and Conny likes Bonny.
3. Bonny is either pink or gray (but not both) and Bonny likes Sonny.

Using resolution, prove that the sentence: "A pink elephant likes a gray elephant" is true.

Additional question: How exactly does the 'but not both' part affect the sentence? I doubt I should be using XOR since we haven't mentioned it once in the entire course.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: First oaf all, the target sentence is horribly written. It should be "There is a pink elephant that likes a gray elephant". To assert "A pink elephant likes a gray elephant" in ordinary English means (if it means anything at all) "It is a general property of pink elephants that they like gray elephants". Lamentably, however, it is a common misconception among AI educators that the indefinite article always (or chiefly) must be represented as an existential quantifier. This is often true for grammatical _objects_, but only extremely rarely in the _subject_ position. ...

Comment: ... Thus, an exercise like this doesn't _actually_ ask the student to translate from ordinary English into symbolic logic, but to _undo_ the author's fatally botched attempt to translate a formula from symbolic logic into English.

Comment: Also, how sure are you that this is supposed to be modeled using _propositional_ calculus? That would require an extremely unnatural representation of the target sentence. It would be much more natural to use _predicate_ calculus.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, I too noticed something was odd about the way that sentence is structured. Also, yes, I did mean predicate calculus instead, thank you. I've fixed the tag.

Comment: @HenningMakholm.  Is it possible to give some explanation of the difference between propositional calculus and predicate calculus to someone who doesn't even know what AI stands for?

Answer (score 1):

If Bonnie is grey then since Connie likes Bonnie and Connie is pink then there is a pink elephant (namely Connie) that likes a grey elephant (namely Bonnie).  Otherwise, Bonnie is pink and there is a pink elephant (namely Bonnie) that likes a grey elephant (namely Sonny).

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases to consider: (1) Bonny is pink or (2) Bonny is gray.

**Case 1:** Bonny is pink

> Then Bonny is a pink elephant who likes a gray elephant, namely Sonny.

**Case 2:** Bonny is gray

> Then Conny is a pink elephant who likes a gray elephant, namey Bonny.

**Conclusion:** In both cases (there are no others), a pink elephant likes a gray elephant. The phrase "but not both" makes no difference to the result, i.e. if Bonny was both pink and gray, there would still be a pink elephant that liked a gray elephant.